# jQuery-File-Upload Plugin - 501 (Not Implemented)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

This question is about: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

This question is very specific. I did not develop the code so I don't know where went wrong at when.

I copied to whole repository to my **Windows web host** running **PHP 5.3** following the [setup](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup), however, using Firefox and Chrome to visit the demo page, I can upload but cannot delete. The Windows server is **old**, still running **IIS6**.

The console has logged:

```
Firefox:
no element found

Chrome:(1st click)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented) :http://webhost/folder/jquery-file-upload/server/php/?file=xxx.jpg

Chrome:(2nd click)
DELETE http://webhost/folder/jquery-file-upload/server/php/?file=xxx.jpg 501 (Not Implemented) 
                                  jquery.min.js:4
send                              jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax                     jquery.min.js:4
$.widget.options.destroy          jquery.fileupload-ui.js:377
$.Widget._trigger                 jquery.ui.widget.js:489
$.widget._deleteHandler           jquery.fileupload-ui.js:537
(anonymous function)              jquery.ui.widget.js:105
handlerProxy                      jquery.ui.widget.js:406
n.event.dispatch                  jquery.min.js:3
r.handle                          jquery.min.js:3
```

And that linked to `php:1` with this:

```
{"file":{"name":"xxx.png","size":14339,"url":"http:\/\/webhost\/folder\/jquery-file-upload\/server\/php\/files\/xxx.png","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/www.newman.edu.hk\/appreciate\/jquery-file-upload\/server\/php\/files\/thumbnail\/xxx.png","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/webhost\/folder\/jquery-file-upload\/server\/php\/?file=xxx.png","deleteType":"DELETE"}}
```

I tried to check the [`UploadHandler.php`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php) but the whole file seems cryptic to me x_x

Comment: Looks like your server is not configured to allow `DELETE` requests …

Comment: @CBore I am not sure, I am going to check that out :)

Comment: @CBroe I changed the server's setting to allow `.php` to use the verb `DELETE`, but it still replies the same errors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here reporting, for whatever reason. I tried that again with the latest library and it worked. Sorry I can't provide further details or help you if you are currently frustrated because I never recorded them. :(

Anyway, that is how I solved the problem.

---

I am also sorry to say the other answers didn't work for me and I didn't remember to comment because I can't access the server at home and forgot after fiddling with it. Please forgive me :P

---

P.S. I also switched to Dropzone.js because jQuery File Upload is too uneasy to use. I personally think Dropzone.js allows more freedom because it doesn't require **any** dependencies.

Here is how they themed Dropzone.js to look like jQuery File Upload: http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html

Comment: @Vohuman I didn't remember to answer my own question, sorry :P I was just scrolling through my questions just now and remembered to end this.

Comment: This is very good that you care about your previous questions.

Comment: jQuery File Upload is a _mess_. Too many dependencies for doing a simple task.

Comment: @Vohuman Yep, and that became a push factor for me because I don't wanna learn how jQuery File Upload does everything and how I should go upon doing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I just lost few hours with this issue... Could also upload and not DELETE... I created a custom ajax function to delete the files manually... and once I was trying to remove the 501 error... I found this in the UploadHandler.php

```
// Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
```

My VPS server was not allowing DELETE requests... as soon I changed this line to 'POST', it ws working with no more 501 errors...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by putting my own delete button code and the Ajax script.

HTML

Replace this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <span>Delete</span>
</button>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

With this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete_us">
   <span>Delete</span>
</button>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete_me" data-name="{%=file.name%}" data-url="{%=file.url%}" data-thumb="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

jQuery

```
//Delete images on select all button
jQuery(document).on('click', '.delete_us', function() {
    var total = jQuery('[name="delete"]:checked').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.delete_me').trigger('click');
    });
});

 //Delete single image
jQuery(document).on('click', '.delete_me', function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('.template-download').addClass('active');
    var data_thumb = jQuery(this).data('thumb');
    data_thumb = data_thumb.split('thumbnail');
    data_thumb = data_thumb[0]+'thumbnail/';

    var data_name = jQuery(this).data('name');
    var data = data_thumb+data_name;

    jQuery.ajax({
        data  : { dataThumb: data },
        url   : "<?php echo JURI::root().'ajax.php' ?>",
        type  : 'post',
        success : function(data) {
            jQuery('.template-download.active').fadeOut(500);

        }
    });
});
```

AJAX FILE

```
<?php
    //Ajax file
    $data = $_POST;

    if($data['dataThumb']) {
        deleteMe($data['dataThumb']);
    }

    function deleteMe($data) {

        $data = str_replace(JURI::root(), JPATH_BASE.'/', $data);
        $thumb = str_replace('thumbnail/', '',$data);
        unlink($data);
        unlink($thumb);
    }
?>
```

**Note:**
Please replace Joomla standard URLs in the code with your appropriate URLs.

The HTTP 'DELETE' request by **jQuery-File-Upload Plugin** was not working in my project too, so I have make custom code to delete images. I hope this would solve your problem.